# How to renumber items when one of them is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a use-case where input controls are listed and a remove button. The user has the option to remove any of the item in the list. I need to be able to check that there is more then one item in the list before I can remove the item. I also need to renumber the `div`, `span` and `input` control. So if a user removes `id=1` I want to remove that item and they renumber then starting with 1.

```js
function RemoveRow(id) {
  if (id > 0) {
    let rowCount = $('[id^=newrowItem_]').length
    if (rowCount != 1) {
      let removeData = `#newrowItem_${id}`;
      $(removeData).remove();
      // Re-number
      let inputdatagripPanel = $("#inputDataGrippanel");
      var inputdatagripForm = inputdatagripPanel.find(".form-group");
      let fieldItemid = 1;
     // $(inputdatagripForm).each((index, item) => {
     //   console.log(item);
     //   let fieldItem = `#fieldrowItem_${fieldItemid}`;
     //   item.attr('id', fieldItem);
     //   id++;
     // });
    } else {
      let fieldItem = `#fieldrowItem_${id}`;
      $(fieldItem).addClass('error');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="inputDataGrippanel" class="col-sm-6 row">
  <div id="inputDataGrippanel" class="col-sm-6 row">
    <label>Rows</label>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_1">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_1" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 1" data-value="0" required="" value="a">
        <span id="spanrowItem_1" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(1)">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_2" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 2" data-value="0" required="" value="b">
        <span id="spanrowItem_2" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(2)">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_3" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 3" data-value="0" required="" value="c">
        <span id="spanrowItem_3" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(3)">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_4" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 4" data-value="0" required="" value="d">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_5" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 5" data-value="0" required="" value="e">
        <span id="spanrowItem_5" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(5)">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Giving `id` attributes a sequential value is never necessary. Also why do you want to show "Row 5" as a placeholder? How does that help the user with their input? A placeholder is intended to give a hint on what the user should enter...

Comment: If you are fixated with using IDs, then you could instead: hide the row, add a "virtually-removed" hidden input and set that.  If you need numbers on your UI (other than placeholder as mentioned above) then you could use [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters)

Comment: Sorry this use case is when the user enters all the information and then wants to remove row 1.  So the placeholder has displayed at the time of the page loading.

Comment: You don't need to change the IDs to change the placeholder text.   If the requirement is that the placeholder text changes, then just change that.  If the requirement is that all the IDs change, then the requirement is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed a missing `span` in your HTML, modified the code that calls `RemoveRow` to be dynamic and added the logic that renumbers

```js
function RemoveRow(id) {
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group');
  if ((id > 0) && (id <= divs.length)) {
    let rowCount = $('[id^=newrowItem_]').length
    if (rowCount != 1) {
      let removeData = `#newrowItem_${id}`;
      $(removeData).remove();
      // Re-number
      /*let inputdatagripPanel = $("#inputDataGrippanel");
      var inputdatagripForm = inputdatagripPanel.find(".form-group");
      let fieldItemid = 1;*/
      let index = 1;
      divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.form-group');
      for (let div of divs) {
          div.id = `newrowItem_${index}`;
          div.querySelector('input').id = `fieldrowItem_${index}`;
          div.querySelector('span').id = `spanrowItem_${index}`;
          index++;
      }
     // $(inputdatagripForm).each((index, item) => {
     //   console.log(item);
     //   let fieldItem = `#fieldrowItem_${fieldItemid}`;
     //   item.attr('id', fieldItem);
     //   id++;
     // });
    } else {
      let fieldItem = `#fieldrowItem_${id}`;
      $(fieldItem).addClass('error');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="inputDataGrippanel" class="col-sm-6 row">
  <div id="inputDataGrippanel" class="col-sm-6 row">
    <label>Rows</label>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_1">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_1" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 1" data-value="0" required="" value="a">
        <span id="spanrowItem_1" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_2" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 2" data-value="0" required="" value="b">
        <span id="spanrowItem_2" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_3" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 3" data-value="0" required="" value="c">
        <span id="spanrowItem_3" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_4" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 4" data-value="0" required="" value="d">
        <span id="spanrowItem_4" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="newrowItem_5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="fieldrowItem_5" class="form-control fieldrowItem mb-3" placeholder="Row 5" data-value="0" required="" value="e">
        <span id="spanrowItem_5" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))">
          <i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:#CDCDCD"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks what if I had another form-group that I didnt want to touch above this ? Can I use the inputDataGrippanel

Comment: @Jefferson happy to help! By "not touching" did you mean not allowing their removal, or did you mean the lack of changing their id? If you've meant that the other `form-group` would be outside `inputDataGrippanel`, then the answer is yes, you can add it to your jQuery/Javascript selector's path (prepend it, to be more precise).

Comment: Yes the other `form-group` would be outside of the `inputDataGrippanel` so I would do something like `document.querySelectorAll('div.inputDataGrippanel.form-group');`?

Comment: @Jefferson exactly, but you will have to use it at two places, because we load `divs` bot before and after the removal.

Comment: one other thing the onclick="RemoveRow(number)" is there a way i can update that too? div.querySelector('span').onclick= `RemoveRow(${index})` can I do something like  this?

Comment: @Jefferson I have already fixed that in your structure. It's now `onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id[this.id.length - 1]))`, which is dynamically depending on the `id`, so if you change the `id`, the `RemoveRow` will also change.

Comment: @Jefferson but now I see that the code assumes the `id` is of a single digit. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Jefferson okay, it's `onclick="RemoveRow(parseInt(this.id.split('_')[1]))"` now. We `split` `this.id` by `'_'` and get the second element, then convert it into a number and pass the result to `RemoveRow`.